# Nodejs formidable async mongoose await issue

Tags: node.js, mongoose, formidable

I'm trying to make a OCR parse of an image.

All the things works well but I have a problem this mongoose and syncronysm.

But cannot use "await" on the mongoose find call as the function is not async. How do I solve that.

Here is my code:

```
    // post processImage
    router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
        try {
            var baseUrl; 
    
            const form = formidable({ multiples: true });
            
            form.parse(req, function (error, fields, files) {
                var imatgeAProcessar = files.image.path;
                var extname = path.extname(files.image.name);
              
                getTextFromImage(imatgeAProcessar)        // OCR process of the image 
                  .then(res => {
    
                        const boss_name_req = res.boss_name;
                        
                        const boss = Boses.findOne({"name" : boss_name_req}).exec();  
 // ERROR HERE // return nothing althought it exist on database (no await?)
   console.log(JSON.stringify(boss));  // writes "{}"               

                        const processedImage = {
                              "success": true,
                              "boss_name": boss.name,
                              "boss_image": baseUrl + 'images/' + boss.num + ".png"
                        }
    
                        res.json(processedImage);
                
                  })
            });
            
        } catch (err) {
            res.json({message: err});
            
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have u tried the query in database? And please provide more info on the "Boses" you imported.

Comment: yes, the query on the database works!

Comment: 1. .find() return as an array. so 'boss.name' would be invalid

Comment: Jackal correct. I changed to findOne.... still same issue. The thing is not waiting for the result.

Answer (score 3):

*edited

```js
// post processImage
router.post('/', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        var baseUrl;

        const form = formidable({ multiples: true });

        var formfields = await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                    return;
                }
                resolve(files);
            }); // form.parse
        });
        var imatgeAProcessar = formfields.image.path;
        var extname = path.extname(formfields.image.name);

        const res = await getTextFromImage(imatgeAProcessar)
        const boss_name_req = res.boss_name;
        const boss = await Boses.findOne({ "name": boss_name_req }).limit(4).skip(0).exec();

        const processedImage = {
            "success": true,
            "boss_name": boss.name,
            "boss_image": baseUrl + 'images/' + boss.num + ".png"
        }
        res.json(processedImage)
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({ message: err });

    }
});
```

Comment: Do not let me....SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: getTextFromImage(), does this function returns a promise? 
and I re edit the code, give it another try.

Comment: Try to place breakpoint or console.log statement in the code to debug which line it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the way... I wrote a callback on the findOne call as :

```
            const boss =  Boss.findOne({"name" : boss_name_req})
                .then( resMongoose => {
                    try {
                        const processedImage = {
                          "success": true,
                          "gym": resOCR.gym, 
                          "boss_name": resMongoose.name,
                        }
                        
                        res.json(processedImage);
                    
                    } catch (err) {
                        res.json({message: err});
                    }
                });
```